# Adobe Flash Player Cache: Does data persist across different users of a system?

Tags: apache-flex, caching, adobe, air, flash

Does anyone know if adobe flash player cache data is available to other users on a system?

For example:
A user logs onto Windows XP, then uses my adobe flex application... and in the process of doing so downloads the signed flex lib... He then decides to mow the lawn and log off.

At about 3pm the same day, his Mum can't hear the TV over the sound of the mower, so she decides to log in using a different XP user account. She proceeds to use the very same flex application. Does she also need to download the flex lib again, or would the data already be cached in the flash player?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flex's app cache is in a user-specific place on all OSs. From [the docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=rsl_09.html), section "About the Player cache":

> Windows 95/98/ME/2000/XP
>   `C:\Documents and Settings\user_name\Application Data\Adobe\Flash Player\AssetCache\`
>
> Windows Vista
>   `C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Flash Player\AssetCache\`
>
> Linux
>   `/home/user_name/.adobe/Flash_Player/AssetCache/`
>
> Mac OSX
>   `/Users/user_name/Library/Cache/Adobe/Flash Player/AssetCache/`

Answer (score 0):

Typically, your flash cookies (shared objects) and cache are here:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\Application Data\Macromedia\Flash Player
```

Which means that different users have to download the library separately.

Comment: I see, where did you find that information. Perhaps this setting could be changed to a global location via the registry or something... *searches*

Comment: I can't seen any mention of it: http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager03.html

Comment: @fenomas: I'm pretty sure Glenn's post says "your flash cookies (shared objects) **and cache**"  Granted, he says Macromedia instead of Adobe (who now owns it), but other than that, the directory you list below is within the directory Glenn said.

Comment: Well, it is a bit skitzophrenic. Some stuff is in the macromedia area, and some stuff is in the adobe area. Techincally, fenomas is more correct but the gist is that it's all in the user's home directory.