# Where are signed and unsigned Flex RSLs on Windows and OS X cached?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, adobe, rsl

I'm looking for the directory where Flex framework swf and swz files are cached.  It's been so long since I've needed to know that I've forgotten.  For testing, I need to remove the files and force the browser to download them again.

Comment: Did you try a Google Search?  This came up; which looks like a good explanation: http://www.kalengibbons.com/blog/index.php/2008/11/clearing-framework-rsls-from-your-flash-player-cache/

Comment: Yes.  I used to have a script to clear the RSL's, which I vaguely recall is not the same as the Flash Player Cache.  Since I need to work on this code a bit today, I'd like to reproduce that script, so I need the location rather than using the Settings Panel.  Oh, it's coming back to me... unsigned RSLs are of course cached by the browser.  So, I'm really just needing the paths to signed RSLs

Answer (score 1):

Finally found it.  [Adobe Flash Player Cache: Does data persist across different users of a system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430860/adobe-flash-player-cache-does-data-persist-across-different-users-of-a-system)

It seems there is some general confusion about the Flash Player Cache and RSL caching.  The referenced question describes where the signed RSLs are located.  Sites referenced in the comments describe where Flash data or SharedObjects are cached.  Unsigned RSLs are merely cached by the browser, so clearing your browser cache will delete them; however deleting signed RSLs isn't as intuitive.